# Use Keyboard on Computer in RDP Session

Tags: windows, mac, keyboard, remote-desktop

I'm using RDP on a Mac to connect to a Windows computer (they are next to each other). I would like to use the keyboard connected to the Windows computer when using RDP on the Mac, and use the keyboard connected to the Mac for local Mac related things.

I tried this but it doesn't seem that the keyboard connected to the Windows computer is being detected/used.

How can I get this to work?

Comment: Is there a setting in your RDP application to use local resources?  There may not be. You may need an application like Team Viewer or Radmin that allows local use of the other machine.

Comment: RDP is not the tool to use here. TeamViewer, VNC, etc, is what you want to use here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you RDP into Windows it shuts out the local user. If you could see the local Windows screen you'd see the login window.
When you RDP into a Mac it doesn't, so both can interact at once.

You would need something other than Microsoft's RDP, like Teamviewer etc.